# Email system on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, web

Does anybody knows what is the service on AWS that I can install to send/receive emails?
And also what to install to create/remove mail accounts?
I found the SES but that is not what I need, I need something to create and manage emails accounts, and also a web interface where users can access and read/send their email messages.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Amazon WorkMail – Managed Email and Calendaring in the AWS Cloud. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-workmail-managed-email-and-calendaring-in-the-aws-cloud/

Comment: I would not recommend using Amazon Workmail. It is loaded with bugs and insufficient support. SES might be a better alternative.